Alvar tracking not working
I built ar_track_alvar package from source since it was not available in ROS Noetic.

Measured a marker, found it to be 9.577 cm square
Started openni2_launch nodes for Primesense Carmine 1.09 depth camera
Ensured that the camera is getting an RGB image on one of the topics Alvar needs
Ensured that the camera is publishing camera info continuously to the other topic Alvar needs.
Set Alvar parameters to wide tolerances (see below).
Started Rviz and added Marker visualization.

Alvar is not publishing anything on the marker topic, and no markers are displayed.
How do I debug to find out what it doesn't like?
Here's what's published on camera_info:
header: 
  seq: 38
  stamp: 
    secs: 1731359329
    nsecs: 518892757
  frame_id: "camera_rgb_optical_frame"
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: "plumb_bob"
D: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
K: [574.0527954101562, 0.0, 319.5, 0.0, 574.0527954101562, 239.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P: [574.0527954101562, 0.0, 319.5, 0.0, 0.0, 574.0527954101562, 239.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
---

Command line:
rosrun ar_track_alvar individualMarkers \
  _marker_size:=9.577 \
  _output_frame:="camera_rgb_optical_frame" \
  _cam_image_topic:="/camera/rgb/image_raw" \
  _cam_info_topic:="/camera/rgb/camera_info" \
  _max_new_marker_error:=0.5 \
  _max_track_error:=0.5



